# Question about meaning of "type A personality" and "free meal"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> I absolutely love to travel whether it be domestic or international!  I have traveled all over the world for work and pleasure (Europe, UAE, Russia, Africa, Canada) but I still have quite a few places on my bucket list to visit!  I love wine almost as much as I love to travel :).
>   My friends and my mother mean the world to me! I would do anything for them and vice versa. I am **a type A personality** and can be high strung at times! I want someone who works hard and is driven but who knows how to balance their work and social/family life. I am not your typical girl. I do not date just to date and I do not go out on dates **for a free meal** . Pay attention to my preferences!

She says **for a free meal** .  Is it an idiom?  Is it a slang or something? What does she mean by saying **a free meal** ?

She also says that she was an **A type personality** . Again, is this an idiom?

Comment: Many idioms can be looked up in dictionaries.  Some related idioms are "red flag", "playing hard-to-get", "gold-digger", and "blue pill".

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_A_and_Type_B_personality_theory for an explanation of "Type A Personality".

Answer (score 1):

"A free meal" is being used literally. In Western culture, it is still the norm in many cases for the man to pay for a woman's meal on a date. She is trying to say that she does not abuse cultural norms and another man's expectations just to get a free dinner. The point she's trying to get across on the whole is that she only goes on dates in the interest of pursuing a meaningful relationship.

Answer (score -2):

"Type A personality" and "Type B personality" are idioms.  People with "Type A" personalities have high-stress lifestyles, and were originally associated with people who get (or cause!) stomach ulcers and heart attacks.

Sharing a meal together is a customary part of American dating.  Traditionally, the man pays for the first few dates; these dates often include "dining out" at restaurants.  Thus, the woman literally gets "free meals" as part of such dates.

"A free lunch" is an idiom, as in the sentence "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch."  Apparently this woman does not think that she can be bought for the price of a meal.  She wants higher priced items, like wine and travel….

Comment: This is incorrect. She is using the phrase "a free meal" in the literal sense; she is trying to say that she does not go out on dates just so that the man can pay for her dinner. She's trying to say that she only goes on dates based on the prospect of a lasting relationship; she doesn't like one-night-stands.